# How to enable Perfect forward secrecy in WIndows IPsec client?

Tags: windows-10, ipsec

Windows IPsec has options to configure several parameters i.e. authentication , encryption algorithm etc. but there doesn't seem to be any option to configure PFS(Perfect forward secrecy).

Comment: Is that the same kind of PFS as the one usually called "Perfect Forward Secrecy"?

Comment: Yup sorry for word packet <will correct it>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option on Windows IPsec GUI client to enable packet forward secrecy(perfect forward secrecy). Whenever windows IPsec acts as client it won't cause any trouble as whether or not PFS will be used is decision of client. In case Windows IPsec is used as server and PFS need to be enabled, one can use powershell command to update the quick mode crypto set to use PFS. Run power shell command with administrator mode to avoid any permission issue.

```
**Set-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoSet -Name "{E5A5D32A-4BCE-4e4d-B07F-4AB1BA7E5FE2}" -PerfectForwardSecrecyGroup DH2**
```

Note : above command will update the default crypto set of windows 10 as defined by windows 10 , In later version this default name can change or user may be using custom defined crypto set in that case "name " in above command will change
Here you can use any DH group based on your prefrence , for more details about quick mode crypto set refer link :
[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netipsecquickmodecryptoset?view=win10-ps][1]

Comment: thanks , this is exactly what i was looking for .